# ListView alternate of using ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-listview

I have created a `ListView` and its custom Adapter. But due to some reason I am not allowed to get items from `ViewHolder`.

In my case `ViewHolder` has only one variable and that is of `LinearLayout`. `LinearLayout` contains the other child views(which is decided and created at run time). When I use ViewHolder and set the tag of holder object, on scroll I am getting the same views again.

1. Is there any other way to stop adapter to create views while scrolling ?
2. Or, while scrolling how can we clear the references of views ?

I have find this but I don't think this will work.

```
    setRecyclerListener(new RecyclerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
           //from here can we use this to clean the memory
        }
    });
```

Comment: A ViewHolder serves the purpose to contain a reference to your layout **children** Views, not the layout itself.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Yes, your are right. But I am adding a single view(Linear Layout) in my cell.

Comment: remove that useless view holder pattern and use `convertView` parameter in `getView` method

Answer (score 0):

`ViewHolder` is meant as a holder to contain ids of listitem layout. 
It is optimization to avoid calling `findViewById` everytime new listitem is created for display by going through data container e.g. arrayList.

You cannot stop adapter in between creating item views.
Only items on display are created.
convertView acts as object being recycled for creating subsequent view while scrolling up/down.
You will not be able to use view holder for the purpose you are trying to achieve. 
Sample usage as below.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View v = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(StockDetailsActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.stock_details_list_item, null);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.model_name_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_name);
            viewHolder.model_type_iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_type_icon);
            viewHolder.model_type_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_type_desc);
            viewHolder.model_stock_tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.model_stock_value);
            v.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

        stockCursor.moveToPosition(position);

        // logic to update data to views as appropriate goes here

        return v;
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        public TextView model_name_tv;
        public ImageView model_type_iv;                 
        public TextView model_type_tv;              
        public TextView model_stock_tv;             
    }
```

Comment: Yes right, but what I need is to stop recreating the views every time without using ViewHolder.

Comment: @AkhileshMani then use `convertView` as in above answer

Comment: @pskink I am not getting you, how to use convertview.

Comment: @AkhileshMani `if(convertView == null) {...` also read `getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` documentation

Comment: @pskink This will not work in my case I don't have Id of any view. A layout  contains children view(child views decided and created at run time) and this single layout act as a cell of list.

Comment: yes, it will work, just create a new `LinearLayout` only if `convertView == null`